# What is the probability mass function of the sum of two independent geometric random variables with different success probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've already seen this answer but I need the PMF of the sum of two geometric random variables with different success probabilities (uncommonly) defined as (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)):

> By contrast, the following form of the geometric distribution is used for modeling the number of failures until the first success

In other words, defined Y such a random variable, its PMF is:

[image: equation]

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643851/sum-of-two-geometric-random-variables-with-different-success-probability) the question is the same as mine but the answer is for the other definition of the geometric random variable

Comment: Is there a link missing for "this answer"? It's not clear which answer you're referring to.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643851/sum-of-two-geometric-random-variables-with-different-success-probability) the question is the same as mine but the answer is for the other definition of the geometric distribution

Comment: The number of trials will exceed the number of failures with $2$. If you know the PMF of discrete $X\geq2$ then can you find the PMF of $X-2$?

Comment: Please clarify the question. The question should not rely on the comments to be understood. The comments may become hidden when further comments are added.

Comment: @joriki I updated the answer

Comment: @drhab by substituting n with n+2?

Comment: Yes. If $P(X=n)=p_n$ for $n=2,3,\dots$ then $P(X-2=n)=P(X=n+2)=p_{n+2}$ for $n=0,1,\dots$